# Need thoughts on profiling of multi-threading in C on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, pthreads, multicore

My application scenario is like this: I want to evaluate the performance gain one can achieve on a quad-core machine for processing the same amount of data. I have following two configurations:

i) 1-Process: A program without any threading and processes data from 1M .. 1G, while system was assumed to run only single core of its 4-cores.

ii) 4-threads-Process: A program with 4-threads (all threads performing same operation) but processing 25% of the input data.

In my program for creating 4-threads, I used pthread's default options (i.e., without any specific pthread_attr_t). I believe the performance gain of 4-thread configuration comparing to 1-Process configuration should be closer to 400% (or somewhere between 350% and 400%).

I profiled the time spent in creation of threads just like this below:

```
timer_start(&threadCreationTimer); 
pthread_create( &thread0, NULL, fun0, NULL );
pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, fun1, NULL );
pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, fun2, NULL );
pthread_create( &thread3, NULL, fun3, NULL );
threadCreationTime = timer_stop(&threadCreationTimer);

pthread_join(&thread0, NULL);
pthread_join(&thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(&thread2, NULL);
pthread_join(&thread3, NULL);
```

Since increase in the size of the input data may also increase in the memory requirement of each thread, then so loading all data in advance is definitely not a workable option. Therefore, in order to ensure not to increase the memory requirement of each thread, each thread reads data in small chunks, process it and reads next chunk process it and so on. Hence, structure of the code of my functions run by threads is like this:

```
timer_start(&threadTimer[i]);
while(!dataFinished[i])
{
    threadTime[i] += timer_stop(&threadTimer[i]);
    data_source();
    timer_start(&threadTimer[i]);
    process();
}
threadTime[i] += timer_stop(&threadTimer[i]);
```

Variable `dataFinished[i]` is marked `true` by process when the it received and process all needed data. `Process()` knows when to do that :-)

In the main function, I am calculating the time taken by 4-threaded configuration as below:

`execTime4Thread = max(threadTime[0], threadTime[1], threadTime[2], threadTime[3]) + threadCreationTime`.

And performance gain is calculated by simply

`gain = execTime1process / execTime4Thread * 100`

**Issue:**
On small data size around 1M to 4M, the performance gain is generally good (between 350% to 400%). However, the trend of performance gain is exponentially decreasing with increase in the input size. It keeps decreasing until some data size of upto 50M or so, and then become stable around 200%. Once it reached that point, it remains almost stable for even 1GB of data.

My question is can anybody suggest the main reasoning of this behaviour (i.e., performance drop at the start and but remaining stable later)?

And suggestions how to fix that?

For your information, I also investigated the behaviour of `threadCreationTime` and `threadTime` for each thread to see what's happening. For 1M of data the values of these variables are small and but with increase in the data size both these two variables increase exponentially (but `threadCreationTime` should remain almost same regardless of data size and `threadTime` should increase at a rate corresponding to data being processing). After keep on increasing until 50M or so `threadCreationTime` becomes stable and `threadTime` (just like performance drop becomes stable) and `threadCreationTime` keep increasing at a constant rate corresponding to increase in data to be processed (which is considered understandable).

Do you think increasing the stack size of each thread, process priority stuff or custom values of other parameters type of scheduler (using `pthread_attr_init`) can help?

PS: The results are obtained while running the programs under Linux's fail safe mode with root (i.e., minimal OS is running without GUI and networking stuff).

Comment: What is the model of your CPU?

Comment: Most likely cross-pollution of cache between threads. Have you tried varying the size of the chunks of data? You should also include data loading in your measurements as it may be a bottleneck, i.e. 2 cores may saturate your memory bus. (Also, if you are not doing it already, you should put your timers on different cache-lines.)

Comment: @Mats: The processor is Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q9950 @ 2.83GHz.

No I did not verified the size of the data chunk. OK, I will try to change the size of data chunk.

However, I did not understand what you meant by cache-lines. How to put timers to cache?

Comment: @Junaid: he means to allocate your timing variables such that they are 64 bytes apart.

Comment: @Tudor: Means the size of the data chunk should be 64B? and why 64B?

Comment: @Junaid: You threadTimer array elements should be separated by 64 bytes each. This is the size of a cache line typically.

Comment: Is there disk I/O involved in this program?  If so, what kind of disk are you reading from and/or writing to?  (e.g. hard disk or SSD or RAID or ?)  I/O performance can be as a big factor, sometimes bigger than CPU performance...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: No the data is not read from any disk. Rather data_source function has a loop, which sends the same 32KB (i.e., 8192 32bit integers).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Also not writing any data to disk.

Comment: @Junaid: Read this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol and this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing for starters.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Thanks for the links. Do you also think putting my timers on different cache lines can help?

Comment: @Junaid: It may, but should be irrelevant. What could help you is, for example, Intel vTune profiler :)

Comment: Hi Mats, Tudor and Vlad,
Thanks. I think I got the idea behind cahche-lines. Let me try and see if this helps.

Comment: Possibly you reach the maximum transfer rate from memory. Also keep in mind that the Q9550 is a double dual core, not a real quad core. Each communication from core 0/1 to core 2/3 has to go through the bottleneck of the processor bus.

Comment: @drhirsch: Thanks for your thoughts on the alert about bottleneck on the processor bus. I also have similar feeling that memory transfer rate could be an issue. But how to verify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since increase in the size of the input data may also increase in the
>   memory requirement of each thread, then so loading all data in advance
>   is definitely not a workable option. Therefore, in order to ensure not
>   to increase the memory requirement of each thread, each thread reads
>   data in small chunks, process it and reads next chunk process it and
>   so on.

Just this, alone, can cause a drastic **speed decrease**.

If there is sufficient memory, reading one large chunk of input data will always be faster than reading data in small chunks, especially from each thread.  Any I/O benefits from chunking (caching effects) disappears when you break it down into pieces.  Even allocating one big chunk of memory is much cheaper than allocating small chunks many, many times.

As a sanity check, you can run `htop` to ensure that at least all your cores are being topped out during the run.  If not, your bottleneck could be outside of your multi-threading code.

Within the threading,

- threading context switches due to many threads can cause sub-optimal speedup
- as mentioned by others, a **cold cache** due to not reading memory contiguously can cause slowdowns

But re-reading your OP, I suspect the slowdown has something to do with your data input/memory allocation.  Where exactly are you reading your data from?  Some kind of socket?  Are you sure you need to allocate memory more than once in your thread?

Some algorithm in your worker threads is likely to be suboptimal/expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Are your thread starting on creation ? If it is the case, then the following will happen :

while your parent thread is creating thread, the thread already created will start to run. When you hit timerStop (ThreadCreation timer), the four have already run
for a certain time. So `threadCreationTime` overlaps `threadTime[i]`

As it is now, you don't know what you are measuring. This won't solve your problem, because obviously you have a problem since threadTime does not augment linearly, but at least you won't add overlapping times.

To have more info you can use the [perf tool](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/articles/t/u/t/Tutorial.html) if it is available on your distro.
for example :

```
perf stat -e cache-misses <your_prog>
```

and see what happens with a two thread version, a three thread version etc...

Comment: This problem still there even if I do not consider `threadCreationTime` and only consider `threadTime[i]` (which now has been split into separate variables following the suggestions above on cache-lines). After following that suggestion, the results improved but the now the bottleneck has been shifted. That is, on 1M data the performance gain is good. But on 2M it drops and then stays the same for even 1G. 

I will also try your suggestion to see cache-misses. Do you think valgrind can help? I am also thinking to try Intel vTune profiler.

Comment: @Junaid : cache-misses is just an example, there is a lot of counter to watch.